# Position Random Shapes

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I want to create a page with a button that on click generates one of three shapes with random sizes and colors - rectangle, circle or triangle.

I wrote code that implements this, however every time a shape is generated, it appears where the last shape was created. Perhaps this has to do with the shape's start point?

I've been trying to fix this issue and search for an answer without success

How can I make **every** shape appear next to each other, and not on last shape? 
To clarify - when a shape is created, it will appear next to or above the last shape, and not **on** it.

(In this implementation the triangle is same size every time - please ignore this)

```js
(function() {
    var shape;
    var svg = document.getElementById('svg');
    var colorsArr = ['none', 'green', 'red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'black', 'pink', 'grey', 'purple'];
    var color;

    // event listener on the button
    document.getElementById("generateShapeBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var randomNumberForShape = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + 2) + 1 );

        // triangle
        if (randomNumberForShape === 1) {
            shape = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polygon");

            // random Size's
            color = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9));

            shape.setAttribute("points","30,4 4,60 60,60");
            shape.setAttribute("fill", colorsArr[color]);
           
            svg.appendChild(shape);
        }

        // circle
        else if (randomNumberForShape === 2) {

            shape = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");

            // random Size's
            var cx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 1) + 1);
            var cy = Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 1) + 1);
            var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 1) + 1);
            color = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9));

            shape.setAttribute("cx", " " + cx + " ");
            shape.setAttribute("cy", " " + cy + " ");
            shape.setAttribute("r", " " + r + " ");
            shape.setAttribute("fill", colorsArr[color]);

            shape.style.padding = 10;
           }
      
        // rectangle
        else {
            shape = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
            var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 50) + 50);
            var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 50) + 50);
            var width = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 50) + 50);
            var height = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 50) + 50);
            color = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9));

            shape.setAttribute("y", "" + y + "");
            shape.setAttribute("x", "" + x + "");
            shape.setAttribute("width", "" + width + "");
            shape.setAttribute("height", "" + height + "");
            shape.setAttribute("fill", colorsArr[color]);

            svg.appendChild(shape);
        }
    });
})();
```

```css
button {
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

svg {
    margin:auto;
    width:90%;
    height:500px;
    border:2px solid green;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <button id="generateShapeBtn" type="button"> Generate Shape </button>
    <svg id="svg">

    </svg>
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your shapes to be centred on some horizon line, then don't randomly generate a Y coordinate.  Pick a Y coordinate for your horizon line and subtract half the shape's height from it.

```js
(function() {
    var shape;
    var svg = document.getElementById('svg');
    var colorsArr = ['none', 'green', 'red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'black', 'pink', 'grey', 'purple'];
    var color;
    var horizonY = 100;

    // event listener on the button
    document.getElementById("generateShapeBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var randomNumberForShape = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + 2) + 1 );

        // triangle
        if (randomNumberForShape === 1) {
            shape = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polygon");

            // random Size's
            color = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9));

            shape.setAttribute("points","30,4 4,60 60,60");
            shape.setAttribute("fill", colorsArr[color]);

            svg.appendChild(shape);
        }

        // circle
        else if (randomNumberForShape === 2) {

            shape = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");

            // random Size's
            var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 1) + 1);
            var cx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 1) + 1);
            var cy = horizonY;
            color = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9));

            shape.setAttribute("cx", " " + cx + " ");
            shape.setAttribute("cy", " " + cy + " ");
            shape.setAttribute("r", " " + r + " ");
            shape.setAttribute("fill", colorsArr[color]);

            svg.appendChild(shape);
        }

        // rectangle
        else {
            shape = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
            var width = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 50) + 50);
            var height = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 50) + 50);
            var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 50) + 50);
            var y = horizonY - (height/2);
            color = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9));

            shape.setAttribute("y", "" + y + "");
            shape.setAttribute("x", "" + x + "");
            shape.setAttribute("width", "" + width + "");
            shape.setAttribute("height", "" + height + "");
            shape.setAttribute("fill", colorsArr[color]);

            svg.appendChild(shape);
        }
    });
})();
```

```css
button {
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

svg {
    margin:auto;
    width:90%;
    height:500px;
    border:2px solid green;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <button id="generateShapeBtn" type="button"> Generate Shape </button>
    <svg id="svg">

    </svg>
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also note that HTML properties like `padding` and  `margin` are not valid for the elements in an SVG.  They have no effect.

Comment: tnx for the answer man! 
its great, but when i run your change in the code the shapes are still one on other. 
how im be able to create **every** shape right next to each other?

Comment: Have a base X value that you add to the random coordinates.  And for each shape add a bit more to that base X value.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do to line them up side by side is to create an `xOffset` and `yOffset` value. As you generate a shape, the offset values are updated. You may also want to create a spacing variable constant so that no matter what the shape's width is, it always maintains the same distance away from the last shape. The `xOffset` value will keeping increasing as you go. For every generate, `xOffset = xOffset + Xmargin + shape width`. Also store another value in a variable that is equal to the width of the green box. When the `xOffset + Xmargin + next shape's width > box width` --> `xOffset = 0+margin` & `yOffset = tallest shape's height + Ymargin`. I was unable to understand how you generate the position of the height.

Another option would be to create a table with white borders (or w/e color the background is) and then append each shape into the table cells iteratively. The distances away from each shape would be different because of the random height and widths, but it's a slightly simpler solution

Comment: tnx for the answer man.
im not sure that im understand deeply what did you mean.

the xOffset and the yOffset can be a attribute of the shape element? 

i generate the height and the width randomly, without any logic.

if you have some time, and you are able to create a piece of code of what you meant, it will be great!
tnx anyway!

Comment: No not the shape element because this will tell you the position to place the random shape. So I would consider it is be standalone variables within the function. If you generate a square with width 100px, then the new `xOffset` should be 100px+10px (margin) = 110px. The y should be initial y value chosen by you based on how it would affect the appearance of the shape inside the top of the box. I think you should try out my second option as it seems a bit easier. Remove all the margins you can from the table cells and make sure there are no border lines.

Comment: Make sure to center the contents in the table, set border to none and iteratively add into each table. I suggest you google things you don't know about and also use Google Chrome's developer tools (right click -> inspect element). Learn how to use the webpage inspector in Chrome because it automatically shows you changes made on the web page and you modify until you get the right design. Once you do, you simply copy paste the modifications to your project and save those changes.